# Adjust img height in div with display:table-row

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables

I have a displaying with display table and table row to have a footer always on bottom and with a variable height.
I put an image in the middle div and I want this image will adjust if the screen is too small.

For example :

CSS

```
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="display:inline-block; height:100%;">
<div style="position:relative; display:table; height:100%;">
    <div style="position:relative; display:table-row; height:50px; background:#fc0;">header with fixed height</div>
    <div style="position:relative; display:table-row; height:100%; background:#FFC6C7;">
    <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/jhsgkm4o5/nuage_525x350.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle; max-width:100%; max-height:100%; width:auto; height:auto;">
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; display:table-row; height:1px; background:#CDFFDD;">
    footer with variable content<br>can be multiline
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usualuser/5pd5jmLv/

In the example, if the screen's width is too small, the picture adjusts its width and height, but if the screen's height is too small I have the scroll bar.
So I don't want the scroll bar but I want the picture smaller.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add this below line in your code and try, it `increases` and `decreases` your `width` and `height` of `img` according to the `width` and `height` of `parent div`, but when manually you resize your browser your image will shrink and it won't look good as height too is `100%`.

```
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" style="vertical-align:middle; width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Comment: I try it but the image no keep her ratio. And if the screen is not enough height it's not solve the problem.